# C# Sort combo box items except the first one

Tags: c#, combobox

I need to sort items of `combo box` except the item at `0th index`. The logic which I thought was store the first value in some string. Then apply sorting of `combo box` items. After that insert that stored item at `0th index` and remove from another index. But this isn't a proper solution for my requirements.

```
string str = cmbItems.Items[0].ToString();
cmbItems.Sorted = true;
cmbItems.Items.Insert(0, str);
```

But with above approach, its not added at 0th index. Instead at sorted position.

Comment: Why isn't it? what is wrong with that approach?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your question would definitely benefit from adding some code to it...

Comment: @Sayse Well, I tried that and the problem is that if I use `cmbItems.sorted = true`, And then apply my approach, then the item is added at sorted position instead of first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Answering my own question. The thing which is missing was disable the Sort property of `combo box` after sorting. Because if sorting for `combo box` is `true`, it will remain true for further items and add them in sorted mode.
So after sorting gets completed, make it `false` and then add the stored item at 0th index.

Here is the code -

```
string str = cmbItems.Items[0].ToString();
cmbItems.Items.RemoveAt(0);
cmbItems.Sorted = true; // Sort the items
cmbItems.Sorted = false; // Disable the sorting
cmbItems.Items.Insert(0, str);
```

Comment: Great answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

What UI do you use? 
For example, if you use MVVM and store items in ObservableCollection this solution may be appliable

```
ObservableCollecton<Item> Items 
{
  get{ this._items; }
  set{ 
    if (this._items != value) 
    {
      this._items = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>Items);
    }
  }
}

void Sort()
{
  var temp = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Items.Take(1).Union(Items.Skip(1).OrderBy(item => item.Id)));
  Items = temp;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't assume what the OP is using. Ask in a comment

Comment: @ardila this might be ok. Its a working example, no matter what GUI framework op uses. He just has to extract the code and use it somewhere else if its not WPF/MVVM

Comment: @Mafi I disagree. The question is not nearly clear and specific enough as it stands to be answered meaningfully. That's what comments are for, to ask for clarification. If the question is later refined and it turns out that OP is *not* using MVVM, then this answer is useless.

Comment: @ardila ok, agreed. Op should provide a [mcve] tho...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sort(Comparison) [List.Sort Method (Comparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can then set the 0th indexed value to be before all the other strings.